# Is there a way to set jmeter properties when using ruby-jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, ruby-jmeter

Is there a way to set jmeter properties when using ruby-jmeter

We are building a performace testplan using ruby-jmeter. Our graphs show granularity as 1 min.
We want to reduce the granularity to 1000ms.
Is there a way to set this up in ruby-jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're [running your test plan locally](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter/blob/91d3cad535ac95930c3698e844647f744caa58b6/README.md#running-a-jmeter-test-plan-locally) you can specify JMeter installation location via `path` attribute. All properties customizations (i.e. from user.properties file) will be picked up.

It's also possible to specify the custom location of the jmeter properties file via `properties` attribute.

```
test do
  threads count: 1 do
    visit name: 'Example domain', url: 'http://example.com'
  end
end.run(
  path: '/path/to/your/jmeter/bin',
  file: 'test.jmx',
  log: 'jmeter.log',
  jtl: 'result.jtl',
  properties: 'jmeter.properties')
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)